# When a UIPopoverController is displayed, how do you change the color of the controls behind the backdrop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, tintcolor

I want to gray out the controls (Like the "Hide List" button in the image below) behind a UIPopoverController when the popover is displayed, just like what the segmented control does by default.  I've tried setting the tint color to the controls, but that doesn't work.

How do I gray out controls when a UIPopoverController is displayed?

[image: Popoover control]

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is actually the default behavior of UIButton. I suspect you're changing the `tintAdjustmentMode` of a superview somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried setting the tintAdjustmentMode for the main view as UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic, along with the other controls that I want grayed out and that didn't work.

Comment: What kinds of buttons are those? System?

Comment: Try changing them to `system` style.